# Why does my live linux say no partition when i try to install it

Tags: system-installation, debian-installer

This has made it so i can't install linux.
Details:
I use a acer aspire 3 with nvme drive and uefi.
I am trying to install neon kde.
I do not have legacy in my bios.

Comment: does the nvme drive already have an OS installed? When your live linux is running can you "see" the nvme drive in `/dev`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us more detail. What exactly are you trying to install? The KDE package or a Linux distribution? Where are you trying to install it? How? What is the _exact_ error you see? What is your partition setup (show us the output of `sudo parted -l`).

Comment: Is UEFI firmware latest available from Acer? Did you update SSD firmware from vendor? Similar model: Acer Aspire 5 Model A515-54-5649  Intel Core i5-10210U Install Tutorial
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2437702 Acer Aspire A515-54G Newer Acer -  CTRL S on the main Tab in BIOS to get the option to change SATA to AHCI  Although with Ubuntu 22.04 and UEFI only Dell with Intel 11 chip, it installed with default Intel RAID mode on using Intel VMD driver which is in kernel but not all older distributions compile it in.

Comment: @JaromandaX the nvme already has windows 11 on it.
the resealt of '/dev' was  'bash: /dev: Is a directory'

Comment: @terdon i was trying to install kde neon distro. i am trying to install it on a nvme that contains windows 11 (not duel boot it). the error is when i try to install the distro from the install app. it only shows my pendrive and it's partations and not my nvme.

Comment: @terdon the output of 'sudo parted -l' is

Model: Kingston DataTraveler 3.0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 31.0GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                 Flags
 1      1049kB  13.8GB  13.8GB  fat32        Main Data Partition  msftdata
 2      13.8GB  31.0GB  17.2GB  ext3         Linux Persistence

Comment: Please ***edit*** your question to add new details, don't answer in comments. That way, it will be nice and clear and you can also use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format as code so it can be legible.

Comment: Also, make sure to edit and explain what you are doing. KDE Neon is not a distro. What actual distribution are you trying to install? How?

Comment: `the resealt of '/dev'`  huh? why would you `/dev` ... nobody told you to `/dev` .... what an odd thing to do